# Are there differences in symptoms with different viruses that cause the common cold?

Tags: virus, common-cold, diagnosis, symptoms, differential-diagnosis

A recent [XKCD comic](https://xkcd.com/2535/) proposed a humorous future pastime in which virus connoisseurs review and contrast the symptoms of different common-cold cases caused by different viruses, with the implication being the development of a differential diagnosis database that would allow diagnosing the specific virus that is currently giving someone a cold. That is, this would allow physicians to go from just saying "You appear to have a cold" to "You appear to have a cold caused by RSV. I can tell it is RSV and not a rhinovirus or adenovirus because you reported Symptom X and I can observe Sign Y in your nose."

Do we currently have the knowledge to do this or is it plausible at this time? That is, is there any indication that different cold-causing viruses trigger distinct patterns of symptoms that could be more greatly documented through research?

Comment: I suspect symptoms overlap substantially between these different “common-cold” viruses and it would require an extremely (impractically) large study to resolve their exact distributions to any significant degree. Of course, no such study exists because it is of no use. If knowing the exact virus is clinically relevant, we have laboratory tests that are far more reliable than a clinical diagnosis could ever possibly be.